# Setup links for pagination pages

Tags: navigation, paging, uri

I have `articles/?page=2`, I need to make it like `articles/page/2` or `articles/page-2`

How to do so?

The [Clean Pagination](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleanpager) module is enabled and on `admin/config/system/cleanpage` I added "articles".

`articles?page=1` is the second page in the pagination link and it looks like in this screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

The module changes the reference to `articles/page/1`, although it would be logical to do so also for `articles/page/2`.

How can it be implemented? What alternative methods are there?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is in Drupal itself. Just visit `/admin/config/search/clean-urls` and enable it :

[image]

**Note :** It needs to be enabled in Apache as well. In Apache **rewrite** module should be enabled.